# Trying to return string(concatenated) through recursion in a binary tree

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search-tree

I can not, for the life of me, figure out this problem!!!
I call an 'encode()' method with a string param.
While I iterate through the characters of that string,
    I call an 'encode_char()' method with the chars of that string.
The encode_char() method traverses through the binary tree and appends a "*" with
    every left traversal and a "-" with every right traversal.
If I come to a NULL node, I skip traversal, exiting the function call and subtract the
    last character added.
eg.

```
return encode_char(node->left, let, codeString += "*"); // traverse & append
codeString = codeString.substr(0, codeString.size() - 1); // subtract last symbol
return encode_char(node->right, let, codeString += "-"); // traverse & append
codeString = codeString.substr(0, codeString.size() - 1); // subtract last symbol
```

GOAL:  When I find the node I am searching for, I would like to return the codeString created and go back to the encode() method that called it.

```
class Morse_Code_Tree{

public:
Morse_Code_Tree() : root(NULL){}
void insert(char let, std::string codeString);
Morse_Node* getRoot(){return root;}
//std::string find(char let);
std::string decode(std::string message);
std::string encode(std::string message);
std::string encode_char(const Morse_Node* node, char let, std::string codeString);

protected:
Morse_Node* root;
};

// THIS FUNCTION IS THE PROBLEM
std::string Morse_Code_Tree::encode_char(const Morse_Node* node, char let, 
std::string codeString) {

if (node == NULL){
    // do nothing
}else if (node->letter == let){
    //cout << codeString << " ";
    return codeString;
}
else{
    return encode_char(node->left, let, codeString += "*");
    codeString = codeString.substr(0, codeString.size() - 1);
    return encode_char(node->right, let, codeString += "-");
    codeString = codeString.substr(0, codeString.size() - 1);
}
}

std::string Morse_Code_Tree::encode(std::string message){
std::string result = "";
for (size_t i = 0; i < message.length(); i++){
    std::string temp;
    char let = tolower(message[i]);
    result += encode_char(root, let, "");
}
return result;
}

void Morse_Code_Tree::insert(char let, std::string codeString){

// set root to empty
if (root == NULL){
    char letter = ' ';
    Morse_Node* blankNode = new Morse_Node(letter);
    root = blankNode;
}

Morse_Node* temp = root;
for (size_t i = 0; i < codeString.length(); i++){
    if (codeString[i] == '.'){
        if (i == codeString.length() - 1){
            Morse_Node* node = new Morse_Node(let);
            temp->left = node;
            break;
        }
        temp = temp->left;
    }
    else{
        if (i == codeString.length() - 1){
            Morse_Node* node = new Morse_Node(let);
            temp->right = node;
            break;
        }
        temp = temp->right;
    }
}
}

std::string Morse_Code_Tree::decode(std::string message){

std::string decodedMessage;
Morse_Node* temp = root;

for(size_t i = 0; i < message.length(); i++){
    char bit = message[i];
    if (bit == '*'){
        temp = temp->left;
    }
    else if (bit == '-'){
        temp = temp->right;
    }
    else if (bit == ' '){
        decodedMessage += temp->letter;
        temp = root;
    }
}
return decodedMessage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function will recurse only down the left tree, but never the right tree since you `return` from the first recursive call to encode_char.

```
// THIS FUNCTION IS THE PROBLEM
std::string Morse_Code_Tree::encode_char(const Morse_Node* node, char let, std::string codeString)
{
    if (node == NULL)
    {
        /* changed to return empty string, vs random nothing */
        return std::string();
    }
    else if (node->letter == let)
    {
        //cout << codeString << " ";
        return codeString;
    }
    else
    {
        std::string rv;
        rv = encode_char(node->left, let, codeString += "*");
        if (!rv.empty()) {
            return rv; /* found something down the left side */
        }
        /* this code now reached, due to no return above, so the right tree is traversed */ 
        codeString = codeString.substr(0, codeString.size() - 1);
        rv = encode_char(node->right, let, codeString += "-");
        if (!rv.empty()) {
            return rv; /* found something in the right tree */
        }
        /* nothing found in right or left, return empty string */
        return rv;
        /* codeString = codeString.substr(0, codeString.size() - 1); */
    }
}
```

Comment: OK. So I've omitted the return command in the two recursive calls. It now falls off the tree. Is it possible to exit the function as soon as (node->letter == let) ?  It is at that point that I have the appropriate string that I would like to return. Without the return on the recursive calls I eventually fall off the bottom of the tree.       Thanks for answering so fast!

Comment: Do I have to recurse the entire tree with this function? Is the logic error in the conditional statements? Thanks!

Comment: returning when (node->letter == let) causes Access reading violation. Use extra param to store correct codeString?

Comment: check the updated version above.  if node->letter is crashing.  are you properly setting node->left and node->right as you build the tree?  node->left and node->right need to be set to NULL right after a node is allocated or in the constructor of the node class.

Comment: I CAN NOT THANK YOU ENOUGH! Curious, why 'rv' as the variable name? I am tracing it through the debugger to understand exactly what is going on. Again, THANKS Mr. Hendrickson!

Comment: Would "" have worked as an empty string return when (node == NULL)?

Comment: yes, an empty std::string() would have been constructed by the compiler for you, since your function returns a std::string, return std::string(); clearly shows the work the compiler is doing behind the scenes.  BTW: `rv` is short for "return value". better than `tmp` and you are welcome.